# What is the proper way to navigate between screens in jetpack compose while there's coroutines jobs to be executed in the viewmodel?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

**Problem:-**

I have a composable `WelcomeScreen` that shows a finish button at the end and when the user clicks the finish button it calls a function from the `WelcomeScreenViewModel` that launches a `viewModelScope` coroutine to save a boolean value using android `DataStore`.

The problem I'm facing is that when the button is clicked the navigation works but the `WelcomeScreenViewModel` doesn't launch, after some digging I understood the problem is caused by `NavController.popBackStack()` which removes the `WelcomeScreen` from the stack which in turn kills the `WelcomeScreenViewModel` which in turn due to `viewModelScope` being a lifecycle aware component it cancels all the coroutines jobs related to the `viewModel` when `onClear()` is called which doesn't give the chance for the coroutine to launch before `onClear()` is called.

**Solutions I tried:-**

- I have tired to call `NavController.popBackStack()` from a `rememberCoroutineScope().launch` block which allowed for the ViewModel coroutine to be launched but transition from `WelcomeScreen` to the next screen didn't work.
- I tried calling `NavController.popBackStack()` after the call to `WelcomeScreenViewModel` coroutine but that didn't make any difference.

I'm stuck, I've been trying to find a workaround and fix this issue for hours and banging my head against the wall.

**Here's some code:-**

**WelcomeScreen**

```
@Composable
fun WelcomeScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    welcomeViewModel: WelcomeScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val pages = listOf(
        WelcomeScreenPages.PageContent(
            imageResource = R.drawable.greetings,
            title = stringResource(id = R.string.greeting_page_title),
            description = stringResource(R.string.greetings_page_description)
        ),
        WelcomeScreenPages.PageContent(
            imageResource = R.drawable.explore,
            title = stringResource(R.string.explore_page_title),
            description = stringResource(R.string.explore_page_description)
        ),
        WelcomeScreenPages.PageContent(
            imageResource = R.drawable.power,
            title = stringResource(R.string.power_page_title),
            description = stringResource(R.string.power_page_description)
        )
    )

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = welcomeScreenBackgroundColor)
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(10f),
            count = pages.size,
            state = pagerState
        ) { page ->
            Page(welcomeScreenPage = pages[page])
        }

        HorizontalPagerIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            pagerState = pagerState,
            activeColor = activeIndicatorColor,
            inactiveColor = inactiveIndicatorColor,
            indicatorWidth = PAGING_INDICATOR_WIDTH,
            spacing = PAGING_INDICATOR_SPACING
        )

        FinishButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f),
            pagerState = pagerState,
            lastPage = pages.size - 1
        ) {
            navHostController.popBackStack()
            navHostController.navigate(Screen.Home.route)
            welcomeViewModel.welcomePageCompleted(isCompleted = true)
        }
    }
}
```

**WelcomeScreenViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class WelcomeScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(private val useCase: UseCase): ViewModel(){

    private val TAG = "WelcomeScreenViewModel"

    fun welcomePageCompleted(isCompleted: Boolean){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            useCase.welcomePageCompletedUseCase(isCompleted = isCompleted)
            Log.i(TAG, "Coroutine triggered! ")
            Log.i(TAG,"welcome page state saved! $isCompleted")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call popBackStack after the coroutine in ViewModel finishes. When you launch a coroutine, you have to keep in mind it is non-blocking.

in your viewmodel

```kotlin
//signal your view when the coroutine finishes through state
val finished by mutableStateOf(false)

//in your coroutine
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    useCase.welcomePageCompletedUseCase(isCompleted = isCompleted)

    //change state to indicate coroutine has finished
    finished = true

    Log.i(TAG, "Coroutine triggered! ")
    Log.i(TAG,"welcome page state saved! $isCompleted")
}
```

In your view you need to react if the state changes,
do not call `popBackStack` immediately on button click, just call your coroutine.

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(viewModel.finished) {
    if(viewModel.finished) {
        navHostController.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

Read more:
[Here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodel-one-off-event-antipatterns-16a1da869b95) is an excellent article on handling events from composables.

Comment: Hi and thank you for posting your answer, it seems like a good solution but the problem is i cannot use `LaunchedEffect` inside the `onClick` lamda as it's not a composable function so i tried to launch is using `rememberCoroutineScope` but that didn't work at all, so i dunno I'm still looking around and figure out how to make this happen , and please if you have any other suggestions please share, Thanks :)

Comment: LaunchedEffect should not go into your onClick lambda. It is independent of your click event. It just reacts to the finished mutableState. Put it outside it will work.